# How to deal with a liar manager and coworkers when I'm going to leave

Tags: work-environment, quitting, people-management

I have decided to resign. My manager and my coworkers are liars, play mental tricks, and mob (bully) people in a subtle way. I was hired to do one job, but after a 3 months of total inactivity I was put on another kind of job, that's boring and does not permit me to learn.

I have to resign on the 1st of June, and the notice time is 1 month, so I have to stay in this toxic place for another month and half. Almost certainly the manager will do various form of subtle mobbing. **How can I cope with this situation, without serious impact to my mental health?** I am already compromised by working with these people for six months, and it has caused me anxiety, possibly even the failure of the interviews I've done during this period.

The managers are all sharks, liars and care about nothing but money. My coworkers are frustrated or have already resigned (almost 20 are in their notice period) or too old to leave. All employees criticize the company, and the company has very unethical bheavior.

Comment: What benefit do you receive by remaining on the job for another 6 weeks?  Why not just walk off now?

Comment: if you can prove that the workplace is causing you anxiety/panic attacks, depending on your jurisdiction's labor laws, you may be able to forfeit the mandatory notice period. But you must provide medical proof as well as cause for this being the workplace tension (which probably require some coworkers testifying about the condition) Again, unless there is a big financial burden leaving NOW, I wouldn't stand there for a minute more.

Comment: You should calm down and consider everything you want to say or do before acting on impulse as the level of emotion that caused you to post this kind of vitriol only leads to bad decisions. VTC

Comment: @JoeStrazzere mobbing means buillying - it comes from the behavior of many small birds against a large one. I believe *subdole* to be *subtle*.

Comment: @Dan, the reason is notification time of one months plus the fact that this notification starts to the first day of the month. As MelBruslan said, I could leave without notification but I would have to pay a lot of money. The proof of workplace and manager bheavior cause me anxiety is too long for my country, and the wait time is comparable with the notification time. Joe Strazzere, it is difficult to explain. They know that certain situation is out of my control, and I can't do the right job because of it, but they say that it's my fault for undone job. I haven't find other job yet

Comment: Document EVERYTHING.  It may not help you now, but it may protect you from any retaliatory action after you leave.

Answer (score 9):

Tell yourself *"These people have no control over me."* They can't fire you - you're leaving. They can't take away your terrific project - you're on an awful project. They can't make you look bad in the eyes of your coworkers or customers - first, everyone knows how awful management is, and second, you're leaving, so even if some gullible person believed a mental trick, what do you care, you're going?

When they make a subtle comment that might be an insult if you think about it - don't think about it! When they withhold information you need to finish a task - tell them (or someone else) that you can't do the task till you get what you want. Relax! You're out of it now. The pressure is not on you, you're leaving!

Find some friends away from work you can vent to and enjoy life with, and put your time in until you can be away from it. Look forward to that, and be proud of yourself for getting out of a bad situation. And if you have quit without a new job, put your energy into getting that new job, not worrying about what things are like at this one. You'll be gone soon enough.

Comment: my main concern is that the next company that eventually would hire me, ask to this company (or company's customer, where I was employed for a couple of months) a feedback. The feedback will b negative because of the toxic enviroment make me nevrotic, and moreover the job was really boring and diferent from the discussed one in te interview, so I did it bad.

Comment: That may well happen. Can you change that by how you behave in the next 6 weeks? I don't think so. Focus on your next job now. Focus on you now. Stop thinking about these coworkers, they don't belong in your head.

Comment: Yes. At this point just do your job and treat any negative behaviors on the part of your boss and coworkers as simply noise.  Irrelevant noise like the air conditioner. Tune it out. Every time you hear some being negative, think "I am so glad I am not a jerk like ..." or 'Only 15 more days" or "that's really pathetic" or "I wonder what I should have for dinner tonight?"

Answer (score 6):

You've made one critical mistake:  You brought your emotions to work.

You have to come to see your job as something akin to a traffic light.  It exists, it must be handled properly, but it is not a part of your life that affects your emotional state.

It is just fine to put dedication into your work, and take pride in your work, but if you are looking for acknowledgement, accolades, or recognition from others there, you are always going to be disappointed.

Invest your emotions in your family, religion (if you are religious), and your friendships.  That is where your investment will be returned.  Work is an exchange of labor for currency.  You have to reduce it to something that simple, slog through it, and be done with it next month.  Do not expect one additional bit of happiness from the job.

It's either that, or let them tear you up inside.

Comment: How incredibly depressing. 9 hours a day in front of a red traffic light? Surely we should expect more from life.

Comment: Wesley has right. I'm not pretending to love alla aspect of my job, or love work at all. But after spending several years at university, and the incredible effort to complete it in the right time (only a few percentage of people complete engineering faculty in the canon 5 years), I can't handle the frustration of this job. I'm not growing professionally, I'm not enjoying the job that is borig and underskilled, I was hired as hardware enginner, put to do software engineer and wrote 3 code lines in 6 months. In all this, I have to manage with the lie of managers and coworkers.

Comment: @Daniele we all (most of us atleast) understand your Frustration, but try and look what you can do and start pointing the finger at yourself. You are already leaveing so anything relating to your current work won't do you any good nor can we give advice that will help since all we could say at this point is get a different Job.

Comment: yes, of course. The question was related to how I can manage the manager/colleagues  in the case they want to damage my career for Revenge, and how to deal with the mobbing bheaviors that eventually (but for me, it's almost sure) they will do during the notification time.

Comment: @Daniele - One other tactic to use:  You're leaving.  Stop seeing yourself as a part of this nuthouse.  See it more as live theater that you have a really good seat for.  Watching people tear themselves up trying to tear you up when you won't let them is actually very entertaining, in a schadenfreude kind of way.